# NameError issue running a python class

Tags: python

this is a class with two functions, trying to use the function inside the class returned NameError message. I called the tokenize function on the postprocess function, on the line of my code that looks like this "self.data['review_text'].progress_map(tokenize)" but it returned a name error message.

```
class preprocess(): 
    df = data
    def tokenize(tweet):
        try:

            token = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", 
            tweet).encode("ascii", 
            "ignore").decode("utf8")  # converts 'ueber' to 'uber'
            token = re.sub('\ |\?|\.|\!|\/|\;|\:|\<|\>|\+|\$|\*|\)|\
            (|\&|\=|\%|\-|\'|\"|\%{', ' ', token)# Lets pass only 
            meaningful characters 
            if '\n\n' in token:# remove header
            token = token[token.index('\n\n'):]

            token = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9 \-\_%])', '', tweet)# Lets 
            pass 
            only meaningful characters
            token = re.sub(r'((\.\s*){2,})', '', token)# removes 
            multiple 
            dots with optional whitespaces in between
            token = re.sub(r'(\s{2,})', ' ', token) # Removes multiple 
            whitespaces
            token = token.lower()# lower cases everything
            #token = re.sub(r'(?<=\s)[\w?!%,.;:\/]{1,3}(?=\s|\Z)', '', 
            token)# removes tokens shorter than minLen
            token = re.sub(r'\b(?!(\D\S*|[12][0-9]{3})\b)\S+\b', '', 
            token) # removes all digits except digits that represent 
            years
            token = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', token)# remove html
            token = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-
            9-.]+', '', token)# remove email addresses
            token = re.sub(r'["\']', '', token )# remove quotes
            token = token.replace('\n', ' ')# replace newlines

            tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(token)


            return tokens
        except:
            return 'NC'


def postprocess(self):
    self.data = self.df.head(58)
    self.data['tokens'] = 
    self.data['review_text'].progress_map(tokenize)  ## progress_map 
    is a variant of the map function plus a progress bar. Handy to 
    monitor DataFrame creations.
    self.data = self.data[self.data.tokens != 'NC']
    self.data.reset_index(inplace=True)
    self.data.drop('index', inplace=True, axis=1)

    self.data.drop(['review_text'],inplace=True, axis=1)
    return self.data
```

i called the function like this
 hei = preprocess()
 data=hei.postprocess()

the error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-48-0806f2cc8d73> in <module>()
      1 hei = preprocess()
----> 2 data=hei.postprocess()
      3 

<ipython-input-47-57d07abbfeec> in postprocess(self)
     30     def postprocess(self):
     31         self.data = self.df.head(58)
---> 32         self.data['tokens'] = 
self.data['review_text'].progress_map(tokenize)  ## progress_map is a 
variant of the map function plus a progress bar. Handy to monitor 
DataFrame creations.
     33         self.data = self.data[self.data.tokens != 'NC']
     34         self.data.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

NameError: name 'tokenize' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure where you encoutered the error (you didnt metion it) but I think its here:

```
train_vecs_w2v = np.concatenate([buildWordVector(z, n_dim) for z in tqdm(map(lambda x: x.words, x_train))])
```

You call buildWordVector there just like that - that seems to be the problem because the function buildWordVector is wihin a class, and should be called like so:

```
classinstance=wordvector()
classinstance.buildWordVector(args)
```

You should try that. Hope I helped (if still in doubt, comment)

Example (imperfect without full code):

```
c=wordvector()
train_vecs_w2v = np.concentrate([c.buildWordVector(z, n_dim) for z in tqdm(map(lambda x: x.words, x_train))])
```

EDIT:
You say you need help with running a function of a class from another function of a class. Say you have a class like so:

```
class testClass():
    def spam(self):
        print('eggs')
```

So say you want to make a function foo() inside the class that calls spam(). You have to ensure that when defining spam(), it (and the function that calls it) has the magic self variable (spam(self)). Then, to call on it from another function all you have to do is self.spam() and it will be called. This is what I am talking about:

```
class testClass():
    def spam(self):
        print('eggs')

    def foo(self):
        self.spam()
```

Additionaly, with parameters:

```
class testClass():
    def spam(self,text):
        print(text)

    def foo(self):
        self.spam('eggs')
```

So, this is how you do it. However, because of this magic self variabe, you have to call the functions in the class differently - by first making an instance of testClass(). How to do it:

Say you already made the class as it is above. First, make an instance of the class.

```
testClassInstance = testClass()
```

then call the functions *using* the testClassInstance like so:

```
testClassInstance.foo()

result: eggs
```

So this is how you do it, hope you understand. If still in doubt, comment.

Comment: Hi Evgeny, it still didn't work. The issue i have is calling a function inside the same class. I have two function inside a class and i want to also use one of the function inside the same class.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, it worked but I still have some issues which i will post

Comment: I'l be waiting.